# Has anyone got a JSP language file for Notepad++?

Tags: jsp, syntax-highlighting, notepad++

I can't seem to find a language syntax highlighting file for JSPs for Notepad++.  Is there one out there?

(Currently, I've just got it set to use Java highlighting, which is a little sub-optimal.  I could knock together my own, I suppose, but I'm hoping the internet has solved my problem for me.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of version 5.6.5, Notepad++ supports JSP syntax highlighting! Hooray! See the release notes at http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Releases

Comment: Well heck!  There you go.  Thanks!

Comment: Bless you good sir! Glad this is the first result on Google too.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using Java highlighting, try applying ASP highlighting to your JSP files, it produces better results.

Comment: Well, granted, but I'd rather apply JSP highlighting, you know?